# How do you to use the lightning-formatted-rich-text LWC component to display Salesforce Base64 Notes (VersionContent)?

Tags: lightning-web-components, richtext-notes

Salesforce Note content is stored in ContentVersion.VersionData as Base64.  The LWC lightning-formatted-rich-text just displays BLOB(n bytes).

The SOQL in Apex looks like this:

```
notesList = [select Id,Title,TextPreview,VersionNumber,CreatedBy.Name,CreatedDate,VersionData
    from ContentVersion
    where isLatest = true
    and ContentDocumentId = : noteIds
    and FileType = 'SNOTE'];
```

The template HTML looks like this:

```
<template for:each={notes.data} for:item="note">
    <p key={note.Id}>{note.Title}-{note.TextPreview}</p>
    <lightning-formatted-rich-text key={note.Id} value={note.VersionData}></lightning-formatted-rich-text>
</template>
```

I'm developing a custom Notes control (LWC) to provide better functionality/features.  I'm currently using a wired Apex method, which is returning the correct List of records.

Because Salesforce uses Base64 for rich text storge and they have a rich text formatting component, it seems natural that there should be a built-in solution, but I'm finding no information in the developer documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The Rich Text component expects an HTML and is what the Note Content actually has, but you just need to decode the base64.

```
base64Decode(content).toString();
```

Comment: Thank you Javier.  It's good to know the solution could be straightforward in some circumstances.  I'm using a wired Apex class (static method) that returns a collection of ContentNote objects.  I'm a C# developer... the code behind is still not so obvious to me.  I would need to pass the blob to a function... not sure where to do the decode.

Comment: Based on my C# .NET experience, what I'm doing in JavaScript "feels" sloppy.  I don't just want to get by in JavaScript.  I want to do it in a solid/supportable way.